# CocoaPods Linker Error: "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11"

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I'm getting an error `Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11` upon building my app. It's caused when I override a function from a cocoapods imported library.

```
import Swifter
class MediaServer: HttpServer {
    override func start(listenPort: in_port_t) throws{
        ...
    }
}
```

Even before building XCode 7 says there's a error in the editor and all syntax highlighting goes away. I did a clean and made a new scheme to no avail.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer was rather simple. Just updated XCode from 7.0 -> 7.2 and it compiled fine

Comment: This is definitely still an issue for me in Xcode 7.2.1